# measuring Variable vector in omnet++ from C++ code

Tags: omnet++

I am working on Omnet++ where I am using the INET4 framework to simulate TCP between two nodes. I made my own machine learning algorithm and communicate with the TCP code. Now I am facing a problem in recording a variable in C++ ML code. How should I record a variable value in omnet++ without emitting signals? I just want to record a variable and plot it at the end of the simulation.
I tried with the emitting signal by adding a signal variable in the .ned file of TCP and also in [TcpConnection.h](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-old/doxy/classinet_1_1tcp_1_1_t_c_p_connection.html#a95af8cb855dbf48f415259c0d3081bdf) file. The problem with that is I have to implement variables in the TCP code, which I did but when I use [state object](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-old/doxy/classinet_1_1tcp_1_1_t_c_p_connection.html#:%7E:text=TCPStateVariables*%20inet%3A%3Atcp%3A%3ATCPConnection%3A%3Astate,protected) in my .cc code it gives me a segmentation error.
Thank you

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide [mcve]?

Comment: Thabk you for your reply. I basically solve my issue by using coutVector for plotting.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right way without signals. As a side note, it is permitted (and encouraged) to create a "self answer" if you solved your own issue and accept it for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution for it. Basically I am using cOutVector method for storing the data in the varibale you can also look in to it here [coutVectoe](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:coutvector)